# Change default C:\tmp location blender uses for video edition

Tags: rendering

I'm new to blender, and I'm using it for video edition on Windows 7.
I have 149400 frames to render and each frame is about 1Mb. So I need nearly 150 Gb to render my project.
These values I got them in the **C:/tmp** folder where blender renders each frame as a 9999.png file.

BUT on my **C:** hard disk I "only" have **50Gb** available.

Is there a way to change this default C:/tmp location so i can put it on a F:/tmp where I have enough space?

I tried File > User Preferences > File
I set values for

- Render Output
- Render Cache

But it changes nothing...

Comment: Do you have a secondary hard drive? By changing the Render Output setting in the Render Settings panel you can set it to render to any location on your PC.

Comment: As above, plus, if you wish this change to be permanent, you can make just this change to you default/starttup file, and then save the older default file with the modified render output folder as your new startup file.

Answer (score 2):

Open Blender, change the Render Output setting, then go to File > Save Startup File. This will make it the default whenever you start Blender.

As a bonus, you can also set up a scene the way you like to start. I removed the default cube and set up a world shader ready to use [HDRIs from Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/p/hdri/).

Answer (score 0):

you can select the camera in the outliner menu, then in the propertys window click on the first icon (another camera symbol) and then scroll down to output. there you can change the output location.

Comment: It's not needed to select the camera just to change render output options; they will be accessible in the Render tab of the Properties editor regardless.